# get_item test if null in Javascript model

Tags: javascript

I've a lookup additional column and alerting its value in Javascript as:

```
var oPicture = oListItem.get_item("Image_x003A_People").get_lookupValue()
```

If I dont add any data in the column it errors, how can this be tested to prevent the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IF condition to check whether lookup field contains value or not. Example:

```
if (oListItem.get_item('Image_x003A_People')) {
    alert(oListItem.get_item('Image_x003A_People').get_lookupValue());
}
```

Comment: Did you use a SharePoint tool to work this out?

Comment: @OrangeJuice, this is a simple JavaScript technique. I did however, test it and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @OrangeJuice this works because `oListItem.get_item('Image_x003A_People')` will return `null` if no value has been assigned -- in JavaScript, `null` is considered a "falsey" value and will evaluate to `false` when evaluated inside of a conditional statement... you can read more about this on SO at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true